# Trigger a select box to drop down either by JavaScript or by jQuery when any other object is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want a select box to drop down when a button is clicked.

This is because we are showing a custom select box in which only the drop down will be visible and the head of select box will be hidden below an image. So that the select box might appear like a custom select box.

Comment: This used to be possible but I do not believe it is any longer for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with the native control. You can set the selected option programatically but not the drop down.

Instead , why not use a div with list items to show on click of the image? You want to show a custom select box anyway. Here's a [great article](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/) to get you started.

If you don't want to implement your own, you can take a look at the plethora of [jQuery plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/) available.